# How to disable build warnings for specific assets?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I build/enter play mode in the Unity IDE, many warnings clutter the console window that have been generated by script compilation of 3rd-party assets. How can I disable or hide the console warnings from specific assets without making changes to those assets?

I anticipate people righteously howling about how I need to fix the warnings instead of sweeping them under the rug. But to those folks, *please consider*...

The code is in *3rd-party* assets--not mine. Typically, no upgrade on the asset is available that would fix the messages, and I've reviewed the messages and judged them to be benign. I realize the value of warnings, but I don't want to dig into 3rd-party code to fix the warnings. I'm also reluctant to change the code in these assets because it essentially gives me a local fork. And then future updates on the asset from the 3rd-party will need to be hand-merged against my local updates. That's time-consuming and introduces risk.

Comment: Maybe smg from there https://answers.unity.com/questions/21796/disable-warning-messages.html

Comment: @Everts Thanks, but the advice given at that link would disable *all* warnings, and in my case, I'd like warnings disabled for specific assets.

Comment: Well, the annoying way would be to find the scripts and add the pragma. Obviously next time you update the asset, it's back.

Comment: Yeah, that may be the best solution. If you feel like writing an answer up, I'll accept it. In any case, thanks for the help.

Comment: You could disable warnings altogether by clicking the warning icon in the console window, since compiler warnings are not that useful in unity anyway.

Comment: @ibxcodecat, yeah, that's what I ended up doing. But it's not ideal as it hides warnings from my code. And conceivably, 3rd party code might have an actionable warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two years later, I can answer my own question. :)

Create `.asmdef` files such that third party assets are in one manifest, and all project code is in a separate `.asmdef`. So in my project, I keep the 3rd-party assets just under `Assets` with `project` one level down.

- `Assets` (folder)

  - `thirdPartyAssets.asmdef`
  - ...other files and folders...
  - `Project` (folder)

    - `project.asmdef`
    - ...other files and folders

This basically "disables" warnings from 3rd-party assets by simply not building them. You will still see 3rd-party build warnings if those assets change or a clean build is made.

The original question was how to disable for *specific assets*, so I'll note that it's possible to arrange the `.asmdefs` to include/exclude assets in different groups. And simply putting an `.asmdef` into the folder of one asset that warning-spams, will cause that single asset's warnings not to be shown except for the cases I described in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to both Erik Hermansen and Adam B for providing solutions.

I went with Erik Hermansen's solution, but modified it slighty, sort of the other way around :) :

- moved all third party stuff into a folder Assets/ThirdParty, and created Assets/ThirdParty/ThirdParty.asmdef
- kept my own stuff at top level, and created Assets/MyAssembly.asmdef

Note that you probably have to add some references to each assembly:

MyAssembly.asmdef:

- ThirdParty.asmf
- Unity.TextMeshPro

ThirdParty.asmdef:

- Unity.TextMeshPro

(maybe some others, depending on your own project)

Comment: Re "moved all third party stuff into a folder Assets/ThirdParty":
I like your organization better. But I got scared off earlier from it by somebody that said there are 3rd-party assets that expect to be found in Assets root. And if that happens, it's a pain to sort out. But maybe it's not a big concern. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I haven't found any issues so far. I use packagemanager to install stuff. It enters the root. Then, from Unity Editor, I move it into ThirdParty.

Answer (score 1):

Put the plugin into its own folder and make an assembly definition if there isn't one already.

Then you need to create a `csc.rsp` text file alongside the assembly definition

Edit this `csc.rsp` and add this line

```
-warn:0
```

This will set the warning level to 0 (no warnings) for that assembly only.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings