# How to allow code analysis only for specific assets in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I run the tests and build for Unity, many warnings appear in the log file. Is there any way to allow only specific assets for warnings? I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67539381/7795991) answer but it's the opposite of what I want to do.